# How to kill all Pool workers in multiprocess?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, kill-process

I want to stop all threads from a single worker.

I have a thread pool with 10 workers:

```
def myfunction(i):
    print(i) 
    if (i == 20):
        sys.exit()

p = multiprocessing.Pool(10, init_worker) 

for i in range(100):
    p.apply_async(myfunction, (i,))
```

My program does not stop and the other processes continue working until all 100 iterations are complete. I want to stop the pool entirely from inside the thread that calls `sys.exit()`. The way it is currently written will only stop the worker that calls `sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This isn't working the way you're intending because calling `sys.exit()` in a worker process will only terminate the worker. It has no effect on the parent process or the other workers, because they're separate processes and raising `SystemExit` only affects the current process. You need to send a signal back the parent process to tell it that it should shut down. One way to do this for your use-case would be to use an [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Event) created in a [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager) server:

```
import multiprocessing

def myfunction(i, event):
    if not event.is_set():
        print i 
    if i == 20:
        event.set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p= multiprocessing.Pool(10) 
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    event = m.Event()
    for i in range(100):
        p.apply_async(myfunction , (i, event))
    p.close()

    event.wait()  # We'll block here until a worker calls `event.set()`
    p.terminate() # Terminate all processes in the Pool
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

As pointed out in Luke's answer, there is a race here: There's no guarantee that all the workers will run in order, so it's possible that `myfunction(20, ..)` will run prior to `myfuntion(19, ..)`, for example. It's also possible that other workers after `20` will run before the main process can act on the event being set. I reduced the size of the race window by adding the `if not event.is_set():` call prior to printing `i`, but it still exists.

Comment: @RajanChaudan A typo! I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.

Even if you were able to end all of your processes when `i == 20`, you couldn't be sure that only 20 numbers were printed because your processes will execute in a non-deterministic order.

If you want to only run 20 processes, then you need to manage this from your master process (ie. your control loop).