# How can I kill a multiprocess pool after my zip is successfully extracted?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, kill-process

I've been written a .zip brute-forcer but I believe its continuing/trying to still find the password even though its found (The passwords are stored in a .txt which is called by `Program.py -z zipname.zip -f filename.txt`

I am unsure on how to stop the program once the password is found and halt the pool. Mainly because I am using `multiprocessing.Pool`. My code is as follows:

```
import argparse
import multiprocessing
import zipfile

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Unzips a password protected .zip", usage="Program.py -z zip.zip -f file.txt")
# Creates -z arg
parser.add_argument("-z", "--zip", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the .zip file.")
# Creates -f arg
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the file.txt.")
args = parser.parse_args()


def extract_zip(zip_filename, password):
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'r') as zip_file:
            zip_file.extractall('Extracted', pwd=password)
            print(f"[+] Password for the .zip: {password.decode('utf-8')} \n")
    except:
        # If a password fails, it moves to the next password without notifying the user. If all passwords fail, it will print nothing in the command prompt.
        pass


def main(zip, file):
    if (zip == None) | (file == None):
        # If the args are not used, it displays how to use them to the user.
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)
    # Opens the word list/password list/dictionary in "read binary" mode.
    txt_file = open(file, "rb")
    # Allows 8 instances of Python to be ran simultaneously.
    with multiprocessing.Pool(8) as pool:
        # "starmap" expands the tuples as 2 separate arguments to fit "extract_zip"
        pool.starmap(extract_zip, [(zip, line.strip()) for line in txt_file])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(args.zip, args.file)
```

Now usually `file.txt` has anywhere from hundreds of lines to thousands of lines (By thousands I really mean thousands; like 300k or 1500k). The password anywhere; from the first to the last line. I am unsure how to implement/place this 'handbreak' for once the password is found. I thought of using a `break` but that seemed incorrect as I was working with `multiprocessing.Pool` and also if I placed it after `print()` in `try/except` it would give `outside loop` error.

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068819/how-to-kill-all-pool-workers-in-multiprocess) thread but wasn't sure if this would work for my instance; as I wasn't sure how could I express "password was found" and pass `event/Event` to `def extract_zip(zip_filename, password)`

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `pool.terminate()`?

Comment: How do I implement that? After `print()`? But then I believe I'd have to pass `pool` to `def extract_zip` somehow, right?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a `Queue` (or some other way to signal between processes).

To us a `Queue`, add lines in your `main` to create a `Queue` before creating the `Pool`:

```
m = multiprocessing.Manager()
q = m.Queue()
```

This gives you a shareable `Queue` which can be passed to the pool processes. Add the `q` to the arguments passed to your `extract_zip()` method. Then modify your `extract_zip()` method to use the `q`:

```
def extract_zip(zip_filename, password, que):
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'r') as zip_file:
            zip_file.extractall('Extracted', pwd=password)
            print(f"[+] Password for the .zip: {password.decode('utf-8')} \n")
            que.put('Done')    # signal success
    except:
        # If a password fails, it moves to the next password without notifying the user. If all passwords fail, it will print nothing in the command prompt.
        pass
```

You will need to use the `async` variety of `StarMap`. So your `main` method looks like:

```
def main(zip, file):
    if (zip == None) | (file == None):
        # If the args are not used, it displays how to use them to the user.
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)
    # Opens the word list/password list/dictionary in "read binary" mode.
    txt_file = open(file, "rb")

    # create a Queue
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = m.Queue()

    # Allows 8 instances of Python to be ran simultaneously.
    with multiprocessing.Pool(8) as pool:
        # "starmap" expands the tuples as 2 separate arguments to fit "extract_zip"
        pool.starmap_async(extract_zip, [(zip, line.strip(), q) for line in txt_file])
        pool.close()
        q.get(True)    # wait for a process to signal success
        pool.terminate()    # terminate the pool
        pool.join()
```

You can add a `timeout` to the `q.get()` to handle cases where no password is found.

Comment: I see. And this supposedly "kills" everything as soon as a password is found, right? Thus no more attempts at unzipping the zip.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate), `terminate()` "Stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work." However, attempts at unzipping that are currently in process, will probably complete. Setting `chunksize` to `1` might limit the extra work after `terminate()`.